# Getting a an array from for loop and use another for loop with that array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5

I have a for loop, and will form two arrays in the loo

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
........
........
$user_insert[] = [
        'keyy' => $value,
        'key' => $value,
        ....
        ...
        ...
    ];
$someArray1[] = [
        /*'user_id' => $insert_id,*/
        'key1' => $value1,
        'keyy' => $value,
        .......
        ........
    ];
}
```

the count of `$user_insert[]` array is 4, the count of `$someArray1` is 15.

after this for loop, I need to insert `$user_insert` array data to the database and use that inserted_id to insert next array `$someArray1`

```
foreach($user_insert as $insert_user){
    $unique_user_insert = array_unique($insert_user);
    //dd($unique_user_insert);
    $insert_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($unique_user_insert);

    foreach ($someArray1 as $someArray) {
        $someArray['user_id'] = $insert_id;
        DB::table('table_name')->insert($someArray);
    }
}
```

So the problem here is the data in the second loop is inserting 60 times(4 * 15). I need to insert only 15 rows.

The data(`$someArray1`) is coming from the first for loop, but I need to add a `user_id` to that array which I get after the insert operation in second for loop.

So how can i insert only 15 rows.

Comment: How do you know which userid goes with which somearray1?

Comment: in the second for loop, am inserting the data, that last_inserted Id, will be the user_id in $someArray1. `$insert_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($unique_user_insert);`

Comment: @EdmCoff has a point. It is unclear what the goal is with your inserts. After having read your question a couple times I can't see why you need the inner foreach with $someArray1. It appears that you should store the inserted Ids from the foreach($user_insert) in a variable, then perform inserts (that you are trying to do in the foreach($someArray1) after that foreach($user_insert) is finished.

Comment: We know you are using those Ids that you are getting from the insert statement. @EdmCoff means your inner loop isn't going to necessarily use the correct key=>value pair to store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are able to access your $someArray1 using the $insert_id value to find the appropriate user data.

```
foreach($user_insert as $insert_user){
    $unique_user_insert = array_unique($insert_user);
    $insert_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($unique_user_insert);

    // Get the user information you need as $someArray1 should be user_id=>data
    $userData = $someArray[$insert_id];
    $userData['user_id'] = $insert_id;
    // No need for an inner loop, just access the necessary properties of the loop you created earlier.
    DB::table('table_name')->insert($userData);
}
```

Your tags indicate that you are using Laravel 5 too. If you are using the eloquent ORM, some of the insertion and ID retrieval can be cleaned up by creating Models for your DB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, each time you process a line from `$user_insert`, you loop over `$someArray1` instead of fetching just the line you need.

The thing is to understand the line you need. As much as I can understand your piece of code, I would say the easiest (most readable) way of doing it is by using a `for` loop, not a `foreach` one :

```
    for( $i = 0, $iMax = count( $user_insert ); $i < $iMax; ++$i ){
        $insert_user = $user_insert[$i];

        // Put your `$user_insert` insert code here

        $someArray1[$i]['user_id'] = $insert_id;
        DB::table('table_name')->insert( $someArray[$i] ); // Note the [$i] here
    }
```

You also may do that with foreach by requesting indices :

```
    foreach( $user_insert as $i => $insert_user ){
        $unique_user_insert = array_unique($insert_user);
        //dd($unique_user_insert);
        $insert_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($unique_user_insert);

        // Now use $i requested above :
        $someArray1[$i]['user_id'] = $insert_id;
        DB::table( 'table_name' )->insert( $someArray1[$i] );
    }
```

Comment: @Juline P I followed foreach by requesting indices. But then am able to insert only 4 rows in 'table_name' table name.Actually, I have 15 rows in `$someArray1` and 4 in `$user_insert` array, as am looping in `user_insert`, am only able to add 4 values to the table.

Comment: My bad! I drove you in fetching `$someArray[$i]` instead of `$someArray1[$i]`! I corrected the sample code. Was that the error ?

Comment: The array name is not an issue, the count of data is issue.

@Juline P  I need to insert 15 values, in table all those values will have some of the 4 user_id, so this loop `$user_insert as $i => $insert_user` will get 4 user_ids , so need to insert a table with 15 values with these user_ids.

But am able to insert only four values.  Am i understood?

Comment: Second part of your reflexion : This is where my understanding of your code start failing ;) 
In your example, `$user_insert` and `$someArray1` SHOULD have the same amount of rows, but `$user_insert[$i]` and `$someArray1[$i]` MAY NOT. I then supposed that the first element in `$user_insert` corresponds to the first element in `$someArray1`.
Let's suppose  `$user_insert` and `$someArray1` are different length. How are the two arrays related ?

Comment: `$user_insert` has 4  and `$someArray1` has 15

Comment: And do you wan't to put `user_id` on each row of `$someArray1` or just some of them ? Which ones ?